# Linker Issues with -ledit (Ubuntu 14.10)

Tags: linker, llvm

Before I get into my question, I'm a bit of a Linux newbie. Anyhow, I'm trying to make my project on Ubuntu, I've just upgraded from LLVM 3.4 to LLVM 3.5. When I try and Make my project I get the following linker error:

`` felix@felix-dev:~/Dev/jayfor$ make
clang `llvm-config --cflags` -Wall -Iincludes/ -g src/*.c -c src/*.c
clang++ *.o `llvm-config --libs --system-libs --cflags --ldflags core analysis executionengine jit interpreter native` -o j4 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ledit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1 ``

I've googled my problem, and asked some friends on IRC to no avail. When I run `edit` in the terminal, it doesn't say anything like could not find command, and I saw that I should `apt-get` the `libedit2`, which I did and it still didn't fix my issue.

Here's a link to the [Makefile](https://github.com/jayfor-lang/jayfor/blob/master/Makefile).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out I just had to apt-get the `libedit-dev` package.

Comment: Had the same problem on fedora 21. I really wonder why ld rejected the library althought it clearly was in the right place. I also wonder why installing the dev package fixed that.